# CreateProcessWithLogonW and AssignProcessToJobObject

Tags: c, windows, security, winapi

I have a Windows service (under WinXP SP2), running under the LocalSystem account, that launches processes using CreateProcessWithLogonW. In order to clean up child processes, I'm trying to use a job object and TerminateJobObject.

MSDN states that the job handle must have JOB_OBJECT_ASSIGN_PROCESS access right, which it has since it's created via CreateJobObject. The process handle must have PROCESS_SET_QUOTA and PROCESS_TERMINATE rights. I think it has them since TerminateProcess and SetProcessWorkingSetSize both return with no error.

Though, AssignProcessToJobObject fails with errno 5 (Access denied). Everything works fine if I replace CreateProcessWithLogonW with a simple CreateProcess.

Am I missing something or is what I'm trying to do impossible ?

Edit: It seems that svchost.exe, which actually creates the process when CreateProcessWithLogonW is used, already assigns the process to an anonymous job. The CREATE_CREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB flag is ignored by this function. So the real question is: is there a way to prevent svnhost from assigning the process to a job ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Jeff Lawson](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/user-104968.aspx) on MSDN:

> **Interactions with Win32 Job Objects**
>
> CreateProcessWithLogonW executes the
> new process as a child of the
> Secondary Logon service, which has the
> outcome of making the process escape
> any Job Object membership/restrictions
> even if the Job Object did not allow
> breakaway.
>
> Furthermore, the Secondary
> Logon service automatically creates
> its own new Job Object and assigns the
> new process into it. As such, it is
> not possible for the caller to
> explicitly assign the new process to
> any other Job Object (since a process
> may only be assigned to one Job
> Object, and can never be removed from
> a Job Object once it has been assigned
> to one).

Does each new process need a different logon? Otherwise, you could create a single process with the new logon and have it spawn new process using CreateProcess that could then be associated with a Job Object.

Comment: Actually there's a fixed set of logons that are needed, so I may use this approach with one process per logon doing the CreateProcess. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I ran into exactly same problem. My way to solve it was -- as you proposed -- to create third process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

we can enable privilege and use `CreateProcessAsUserW`  instead