# Job Control with CreateProcessWithLogonW

Tags: security, winapi, process, impersonation

An application I'm writing requires the execution of potentially malicious code to be executed on a host system. The code only interacts with `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`, and should not attempt to interact with the filesystem or network.

I've restricted network access through a firewall rule, and filesystem access through running the process as an unprivileged user created through `NetUserAdd` with `CreateProcessWithLogonW`. Finally, I assign the process to a job object that limits memory and active processes.

This works fine on Windows 8, but when I tested it on a Windows 7 machine (the deployment platform), I found that `AssignProcessToJobObject` failed with an access denied, despite running as administrator. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1287926/1226852) answer, I found that

> CreateProcessWithLogonW executes the new process as a child of the
>   Secondary Logon service, which has the outcome of making the process
>   escape any Job Object membership/restrictions even if the Job Object
>   did not allow breakaway.
>
> Furthermore, the Secondary Logon service automatically creates its own new Job Object and assigns the new process into it.

So while this works on Windows 8 which allows nested job objects, it fails on Windows 7 and under.

The same answer suggests spawning an agent process under the Secondary Logon service and using it to spawn the process with the `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` flag. However, when attempting this, the agent's `CreateProcess` call fails with 5 `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, because the job Secondary Logon puts the agent in does not allow breakaways.

How can I assign a process created under another user to a job object on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've done some experimentation, and can confirm that both [CreateProcessWithLogonW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CreateProcessWithTokenW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) put the newly created process into a job object.

However, [CreateProcessAsUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not.  So this is probably the best workaround, though it does require the "Replace a process level token" privilege.  You can either run the code from a context that already has this privilege (i.e., a service configured to run as local service or network service) or you can grant the privilege to the user account that will be used to run the code.

See also [Shattering the myths of Windows security](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.co.nz/2014/01/shattering-myths-of-windows-security.html) at the Invisible Things Lab's blog (and in particular the linked whitepaper) which describes various issues with running potentially malicious code in a limited user account.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I only needed to assign some limits on the process (memory limit & active process limit), and not make any further use of the spawned process' job object. Since all `CreateProcess` variants (`CreateProcessWithLogon`, `CreateProcessWithToken`, etc) seem to end up spawning the process under the Secondary Logon Service which assigns the process to a job, I reasoned that as long as I can get a handle to the service's job, I could impose whatever limits I wanted.

It would be convenient to call `OpenJobObject` to fetch the Logon Service's job object, but the latter creates the job with a null name. Therefore, I resorted to enumerating the Logon Service's handles, and checking which job handle is the right one through `IsProcessInJob`. It sounds dirty, sure, and I'm not certain its all too reliable, but following [this](http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic18892.html) post on sysinternals (as recommended per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13502329/1226852) answer) finding the right handle did not turn out to be too hard. Note that `SeDebugPrivilege` is required for this step to work.

After that, it was a simple matter of imposing a `JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation` on the job through `SetInformationJobObject`. For good measure, I also added a `JobObjectBasicUIRestrictions` to at least make it bit harder for an attacker.

And that's all!

However, as @Harry Johnston made clear, this form of sandboxing is **[not impervious](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.co.nz/2014/01/shattering-myths-of-windows-security.html)**. But it's *good enough* in my case.